# How does one basically use lastpass-cli?

Tags: command-line, lastpass

In searching for a LastPass client on Ubuntu, I found [lastpass-cli](https://github.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli). I took a look at the documentation but I still do not understand how to basically use it.

I managed to log into my account but now I am wondering how to cover the following use cases:

- How do I retrieve the password for a specific website?
- How do I retrieve the email account for a specific website?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's some fairly limited documentation [here](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/lastpass-command-line-application/).  You have to click on the 'Create, edit, and retrieve passwords on the command line' or 'lpass subcommands' drop downs on that web page.

A full manual page with examples is available [on the Lastpass github page](http://lastpass.github.io/lastpass-cli/lpass.1.html).

To retrieve the password for a specific website use:

```
lpass show --password sitename
```

You can also add the `-c` option to clip the password to your copy buffer.

Retrieving the email account for a website isn't as clear, as it depends upon in which field it's stored, if the email address is your username then use:

```
lpass show --username sitename
```

Otherwise using the correct field in place of `--username` should work, `--id` or `--name` may be good choices, or you can specify `--field=FIELD`. Failing that, look at all of the stored fields using:

```
lpass show --all sitename
```

Additionally you can view all of your stored information using:

```
lpass ls
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I see the actual password instead of, for instance, `Default/google.com [id: 1444152536]`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, is the local copy synced with the server? I've just found the man page online, I'll update the answer with the link, I think the examples at the bottom of the page will help to make it clear.